# Paging scroll view with child view controllers

Tags: ios, scrollview

What is the best practice for implementing a horizontal scroll view with paging, with one view controller per page?

Is the [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) example still the best way to implement this now that iOS5 has API for view controller containers/containment?

Comment: What approach you are using now? I use method shown in apple PageControl example. It works, but there are still some situations where errors appear: Rotation releated, probably due the fact that the ScrollView is not a ViewController.

Comment: I used a UIPageViewController with UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll, I ran into a lot of edge cases adding new view controllers to the start and end of the scroll view which made it not much easier to implement than the PageControl type approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this question is a little old, but as of iOS 6, UIPageViewController has a new transition style property called [`UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle) which lets you use the page controller for a use case like yours, with simple scrolling between pages instead of the iBooks-style page curl transitions.

You should also watch the 2012 WWDC video number [223 - Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?include=223#223) where they basically transition an old app that uses the method you describe to the new UIPageViewController with scroll style transition.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be that it depends on your goal. If you want to make an app as efficiently as possible, I would just use the way it is done in the sample code. I have used it before, and I would do it again.

On the other hand, if your goal is to learn about view controller containment, how it works and how to use it, this might be a good case to try it out. If you go that way, don't forget to check out the WWDC video "Implementing UIViewController Containment" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).

Comment: Thanks I watched the WWDC video, its not one of Apple's best, very confusing.  The video discusses UIViewController containment in the context of managing different portions of the screen which is a different case to a scroll view.  Problem with the page control example is that its out of date.  No storyboards etc.

Answer (score 2):

Appears best practice as of iOS5 is to remain using the same method as the PageControl example.  That is one controller class (note not a view controller).  With child view controllers for each page.

As of now there is no documented better way to implement a paging scroll view using view controller containment methods included in iOS5.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a UIPageViewController instead.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The UIPageViewController doesn't support horizontal paging without the page flip animation which is what I need.

Answer (score -1):

I think UIPageViewController can go horizontally:

```
- (id)initWithTransitionStyle:(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle)style navigationOrientation:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation)navigationOrientation options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

And

```
enum {
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal = 0,
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical = 1
};
typedef NSInteger UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation;
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The UIPageViewController only supports page turns when moving between pages.  I am looking for the best way to scroll horizontally between multiple pages.  With one page per view controller as the pagecontrol example does

Answer (score -1):

If you add your View Controllers views (myViewControllerOne.view) to the UIScrollView - and then appropriately frame them to appear horizontally - when the user interacts with that view inside of the scroll view methods in the View Controller will be called.

By this I mean if you have MyViewControllerOne.view as a sub view inside of your scroll view, when you scroll to that 'page' of the scroll view and press the button the attached method (IBAction etc) in MyViewControllerOne will be called.

This should give you all the functionality you need such as adding UI Elements, tables, another scroll view, etc.. These elements will be controlled from their originating View Controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks RachelD thats what I have done.  Question was more about what is best practice.  Note adding one view controllers view to anothers view hierarchy can be problematic.  See http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/

Comment: This is not the proper way, you should never do it this way!